# Is it possible to edit and save text in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, cordova

I am developing an app in PhoneGap (and Xcode, XML & HTML) which does basic functions like write a file onload and read it to the user etc. i'm at the point where i have been asked to read a file into a textarea and allow the user to edit it and save the edits to the file. Using PhoneGap, is it possible to do so? I'm having trouble finding out how to save edits - which is the point i find trouble with.

Please note I'm new to XML and PhoneGap so any help wold be greatly appreciated. If you could tell me if it's possible to edit and save the edits using the languages i am using then that would be fantastic, although if it is possible could you direct me to sites where i could find out how to do it/give me code here?

Thank you so much in advance xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read any files or write any files to the system using PhoneGap. [Read the documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) for it.

If the file is XML, then you gonna have to parse it and [read using JavaScript](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript).

You must try something first and update the comment section with the specific error you are encountering then users here will be able to help you out. Good luck.

Comment: ok thank you. the problem was i couldn't find any documentation telling me how to save any edits done to a file so i wondered if it was possible